# Install the latest Opencart version? Please read the complete question below

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-3, opencart2.3

Could anyone please advise what folders and files in Opencart do not need to be uploaded to protect the theme if I install the latest Opencart version?

Comment: If you updating for example from OC2.3 to OC3.0.x theme you'll also must update. If you updating from OC3.0.2 to OC3.0.3 your theme should work. In both cases you must upload all files which are in OC installation upload folder.

Comment: @K.B. Thanks, got your idea.